# ModuleNotFoundError: Selenium is not found despite on the `pip list`

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pip, dependencies

I am trying to run a python script on my system with selenium, but I keep running into a 'NoModuleFoundError' error in VS Code. The annoying part is when I check my dependencies, it lists selenium on there.

```
py_files> py .\appleExtract.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py_files\appleExtract.py", line 2, in <module>
    import selenium
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
py_files> pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
...
requests           2.31.0
selenium           4.18.1
setuptools         69.1.1
...
```

Additionally, I made sure my Python executable and scripts were added to my path variable. I also used `pip show selenium` to get the file location of selenium and added it to the path variable. I uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code as well.

I ran this in Jupyter Notebooks and it was working fine, but VS Code keeps giving me that error.

If anyone could offer any insight or troubleshooting, I am in need of some assistance

Comment: The problem is that you have (at least) two different installations of Python on your computer.  `py` and `pip` are using different Pythons.

Comment: Please update the question and add the output of this command `pip show selenium` and the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @JohnGordon I am such an idiot. This had wasted 2ish hours, thank you so much fellow Gordon!

Comment: Sorry did not see the later response but I literally overlooked that fact. Literally just needed to switch python for py and it worked fine.